# Error: Not Found: Project <project-id>

Tags: google-bigquery

I've recently signed up to Google BigQuery for curiosity's sake and saw that it allows one to play with sample data sets without enabling billing. I followed the installation steps, first creating a Project named "Test Cloud Project" and then enabled BigQuery in the services tab of GoogleAPI.

I have tried running the following:

```
 SELECT repository.url FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested] LIMIT 1000
```

and receive the error `Error: Not Found: Project p-testcloud-bren`

Did I miss a setup step somewhere or do you have to enable billing to actually query the sample datasets?

Comment: How did you run the query? API, bq command line tool, web UI?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can't find much related to the error and I'm sure I've completed all the steps.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need billing enabled to run a query on a publicdata:sample table (the first 100GB of data processed per month is free of charge).

If you are making your own API calls, double check that you have the "project id" correct. You should be able to use either the project number (a unique integer value) or the project id (an alpha numeric value you can choose) for your requests to the BigQuery API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried going through and adding project by the project ID and nothing happens. The project appears on the bar on the left, as does the sample dataset, but when I run a query against it I get this error. http://i.imgur.com/1o1jP.png   Did I miss a step in setting up the project?