# Google BigQuery - "Not Found: Project [project-id]

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I'm having a problem getting started with Google BigQuery. I'm certain I have done everything correctly to create and configure the account. But when I go to the web interface, the it seems unable to find my project. I cannot create/upload any new data and I can't even query the sample data set. All the interface returns is:

Not Found: Project [my-project-id]

However, in the same window, the project name and ID is being listed in the panel on the left...so it looks like BigQuery is aware of my project in some sense. Screen shot below:

[image: Project not found but also listed]

I am at a loss of how to rectify this. Does anyone have any ideas of something I might be missing in configuration and/or setup?

Best regards,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently set the ID on your project (e.g. xs-analytical-park-g)? If so, there may be a dataset that uses the old name (which was the numeric id of the projcet) which confuses the UI. We periodically search for changed project names and apply updates, but sometimes this can take a while.

I've just checked and it looks like our data should be up-to-date with respect to the project ids, so please let me know if this problem still persists.

Comment: I haven't changed anything on the project. Its exactly as the Getting Started instructions created it. Unfortunately the problem still persists:

Not Found: Project xs-analytical-park-g

Even though the project is listed in the panel on the left. Any suggestions what I can change to avoid confusing the UI?

Comment: Hi Michael. Do you have any suggestions for this? I see that I am not the only person with this problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526898/error-not-found-project-project-id) and I am quite keen to get moving on using BigQuery as soon as possible.